# How to override default required error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I have an old C# MVC 2.0 web application.

Whenever I use a `[Required]` attribute, the default validation error message goes:

> The [whatever] field is required.

My problem is that the application isn't in English, so I basically have to change the attribute call to `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Le champ [whatever] est requis.")]` everywhere.

Is there a way to override the default error message so I only have to specify it when I want a specific message?

I'm looking for something like:

```
DefaultRequiredMessage = "Le champ {0} est requis.";
```

Comment: I didn't get, what's your problem with `[Required(ErrorMessage = "MyNotEnglishMessage")]`?

Comment: I don't want to have to write the same message everywhere in my app, I'd like to follow the DRY principle

Comment: Could you not just install the French language pack and set CurrentUICulture to a French culture (e.g. fr or fr-FR)?  Or if you don't want to install a language pack, use a custom resource manager: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347650/how-to-use-dataannotations-errormessageresourcename-with-custom-resource-solutio

Comment: @Joe this is a very old app, so I don't even know if I could find the French language pack, and I don't really want to take a risk to mess up everything if it doesn't exactly match the one needed. I think S.Akbari's solution is close to your second option, so I'd rather see if this works as expected as it has little chances to mess up things. However, I agree that having a French language pack would be a great solution!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a class and inherit it from [`RequiredAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2). Something like this:

```
public class CustomRequired: RequiredAttribute
{
    public CustomRequired()
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "Le champ est requis.";
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public class CustomRequired: RequiredAttribute
{
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string whatever)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage)
            ? ErrorMessage
            : $"Le champ {whatever} est requis.";
    }
}
```

You should use `CustomRequired` with your properties, rather than `[Required]`.

Comment: How would you change it to include the field name in the error message?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `CustomRequiredAttribute` instead of `CustomRequired`? Anyway thank you for this, let me just try it and if it works as expected I'll accept this answer

Comment: @Rafalon It is just the name of your custom class. Feel free to name it to whatever you like :)

Comment: Yeah, I just thought it should end with `Attribute` so we can use `[CustomRequired]`

Answer (score 2):

**Please perform the below operation to override default required error message:**

- Create a custom adapter inheriting the RequiredAttributeAdapter as below :

---

```
public class YourRequiredAttributeAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<RequiredAttribute>
{
    public YourRequiredAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, RequiredAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attribute.ErrorMessage)
            )
        {
            attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType ="Your resource file";
            attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName = "Keep the key name in resource file as "PropertyValueRequired";
        }
    }

}
```

- Register the Adapter in Global.asax Application_Start() as below:

---

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredAttribute), typeof(YourRequiredAttributeAdapter));
```

---

- Resource File Configuration:
  [image]